# Create MBTiles from a single input raster (QGIS processing)

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-processing, mbtiles

In a QGIS processing, I would like to generate MBTiles from a raster source (file or WMTS). The tools offered by QGIS never take a layer as input but a map extent (and therefore generates an output that combines all layers displayed on the canvas). Is there a tool to generate MBTiles from a single layer?

The process must be used in a batch process and iterate over several layers. It is therefore not possible to show and hide layers in the layers panel.

Comment: At the risk of providing a simplistic solution, you can Hide All Layers in the Layer Panel, then enable the raster layer, and finally use Generate XYZ Tiles, using the raster layer as the extent. If you have restrictions that would prevent this being a solution, consider editing your original question.

Comment: If you are just trying to convert single raster files into MBTiles formats, it's not clear from your question why you need QGIS. Can you just use GDAL directly? eg `gdal_translate -of mbtiles -co "TILE_FORMAT=PNG8" C:/input.tif C:/output.mbtiles`

Comment: The advantage of QGIS is that I can generate tiles from a WMTS (I edited my question). But the layer has to be displayed. I think this is not possible with gdal.

Comment: It is possible to convert from WMTS to other formats using gdal_translate. But I am not sure what you mean when you say "the layer has to be displayed".

Comment: Thank you I will try with gdal_translate